# How to cast value from database entity to a list of strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, casting

If I have this LINQ code:

```
        object fA = from f in entities.Friends
                    where f.Friend_B == User.Identity.Name && f.AreFriends
                    select f.Friend_A;
```

In the database table Friend the value of Friend_A is defined as nvarchar(50).

What I need to achieve is to convert the list of friends returned to this variable `object fA` to a list of strings; `List<string>` or any kind of enumerable collection or array.

I tried to do that many ways but with no success. This is the last try:

```
    List<string> allFrinds = new List<string>();

    using (FacebookDataEntities entities = new FacebookDataEntities())
    {
        object fA = from f in entities.Friends
                    where f.Friend_B == User.Identity.Name && f.AreFriends
                    select f.Friend_A;

        IQueryable<string> faa = (IQueryable<string>)fA;

        foreach(string s in faa)
        {
          allFrinds.Add(s);
        }
```

At the end `allFrinds` is empty!.

Comment: Try using `var` instead of `object`. `var` is more dynamic and you can play it as a variable or a list or anything. Also, you wont need that explicit conversion unless necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this directly:

```
 var fA = (from f in entities.Friends
                    where f.Friend_B == User.Identity.Name && f.AreFriends
                    select f.Friend_A).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var allFriends = entities.Where(x => x.Friend_B == User.Identity.Name && x.AreFriends)
                             .Select(x => x.Friend_A).ToList()
```